# Access URL by program in C# for Session Managed Website

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I want to request the URL by program not by Browser and getting the response in C#  for session managed website for example, first C# will  hit the login page (using userName and Password) then next page, I am using `request.getresponse()` as `HttpwebResponse`,  but it login successfully and when I hit the next page URL then its saying session is null  and its Redirecting to the login page (and I am getting Response URI as login page URL ). How can I access the website using URL hit  for session managed website.

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far.

Comment: request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: " + session_details[index + 5]);
                request.UserAgent = session_details[index + 6];
                request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: " + session_details[index + 7]);
                request.Host = session_details[index + 8];
                request.CookieContainer = containsCookies;

Comment: response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

Comment: Please Reply ASAP

Comment: first time when i login with request body that contains usename and password then  it loggin successfully and i am getting the response URI as home page and when i am making request for next page URL then its saying session is null

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the site uses Cookies and you need to include the cookies you get from the response in your subsequent requests:

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
```

Comment: Thanks  for  this   Actually i need to Access  all URL in Hidden Browser (Without opening the browser but internally the Request will be Proccessed in Browser  so that it will access all the url after the login page URL)

Comment: So you want the program to make the request for you first, then you want to be able the open a "hidden" browser to make subsequent requests? Is that correct?

Comment: yes (the Request should be Proccessed in hidden Browser like Load runner)

Comment: In that case what you are talking about is high-jacking the session. In your current case you cannot make a request with a .net bot then use Load Runner because two different sessions will be established. Now if you so happen to get access to the Load Runner API, then that would be a different story.

Comment: when i Create a Request using  request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(session_details[index + 2]) as HttpWebRequest;    then it maintain the Session for one thread

Comment: when i Create a Request using  request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;    then it maintain the Session for one thread